# Converting unsigned integer value into byte array

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes an `unsigned` value and transforms it into a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`. The requirements (and post conditions) are as follows:

1. The code must utilize "modern C++" up to C++14
2. The focus is on readability/maintainability first, performance second
3. The most significant byte must be at index 0.
4. The lease significant byte must be at index `size()-1`.
5. The return type cannot be changed; this is a requirement stemming from other code not shown in this context (larger application requirement). Also avoids a conversion from one container to `std::vector`.
6. The resulting vector must be as compact as possible. For values that decompose into fewer bytes than `sizeof(unsigned)`, the resulting vector must not contain unnecessary MSB's (that is, zero value bytes).
7. The code must be endianness-agnostic and portable to various other architectures and platforms.

Here is the current implementation I have:

```
using BinaryStreamByteVector = std::vector<std::uint8_t>;

BinaryStreamByteVector CreateMultiByteInteger(unsigned value)
{
    BinaryStreamByteVector value_bytes;

    while (value != 0)
    {
        std::uint8_t byte = value & 0xFF;
        value_bytes.insert(value_bytes.begin(), byte);

        value >>= 8;
    }

    return value_bytes;
}
```

([Live Sample on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3bf4886fc2df235))

I can't think of a better implementation for `CreateMultiByteInteger`, so I'm hoping for other ideas that meet the requirements above.

Comment: Eh... To me it looks very good as it already is. Pretty performant, well written with proper naming and whitespace. Would you accept this as an answer? Our [Meta policy](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94/should-your-code-seems-fine-answers-be-acceptable) accepts "your code is fine" answers.

Comment: What would be overkill here but ideal is probably a template function returning a `const` array or a `const std:: array` (for retaining size information), which varies the size of the array returned using the `sizeof` operator on `unsigned`. That would be absolutely performant, I guess. The algorithm is perfect. You even include the masking of the higher-order bits. Unfortunately, you have a restriction on the return type, so this wouldn't help. However, maybe the idea of making it a template function will still help?

Comment: I guess what I was hoping for was a different approach, like masking from MSB to LSB (I'm currently doing the reverse of that). But I wasn't able to find an easy way to do that. Not trying to overthink or over engineer this; but definitely wanted to try getting different perspectives. Thanks guys; I'd be happy to accept an answer that says "It's good enough"; gives me an opportunity to check up-votes of that as a way to measure for general consensus.

Comment: Does this need to be endianness-independent? You state what your requirements are for the resulting vector, but what about the input integer? If you can assume a particular endianness (e.g., because you're only targeting one architecture and don't care if your code is portable), then you can make this *a lot* faster without adding much complexity. Otherwise, you should probably stick with the general approach you've used here, unless speed is a big concern (which you indicate it is not).

Comment: @CodyGray, It's always better to be independent of as much stuff as possible, especially if the code needs to be portable and performance isn't a concern (but thankfully you can always assume the standard library).

Comment: I did miss a requirement; the algorithm must be endianness agnostic, since this code must be portable to different platforms and architectures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Observations

Your code is beautiful (proper naming conventions followed, proper whitespace usage, *very* readable. I particularly like the type-aliasing, which helps make the whole thing that much more readable than a `typedef` or `#define`). I cannot personally think of any more ways to make your code more readable, however, I do have 1 suggestion.

The algorithm you currently follow is standard and ideal (you even have proper masking of higher-order bits); and in my honest opinion any other algorithm would be tantamount to obfuscation; but if you assume that the code will only ever run on a particular architecture, you could probably unroll the loop.

## Suggestion

1. Make your function parameter `const`. Although C++ is call-by-value, making it explicitly `const` and mutating a local copy of the variable is never a bad idea, and it does make your function contract that much clearer.
2. On the performance side, since on any reasonable computer `unsigned` will have maximally 16 bytes (64 bits of 8 bytes is the case for all common architectures, except for probably some microcontrollers which will have less, even as less as 1 byte) (note that the upcoming RISCV architecture does have a native 16-byte (128-bit) integral data type, but the 64-bit one is the default), you can easily make this function a template, such that the computation of the byte vector can be done at compile time without much overhead and incur no runtime overhead.

   You can probably even pre-set the capacity of your `std::vector` utilising `sizeof(unsigned)`.

   Although I'm not sure if this suggestion will work in the constraints of your application.

Comment: Ironic that you say here *"since on any reasonable computer unsigned will have maximally 4 bytes"*, yet just replied to me with [a comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152355/converting-unsigned-integer-value-into-byte-array?noredirect=1#comment287708_152355) that says: *"It's always better to be independent of as much stuff as possible"*. While portability has its virtues, I don't agree that it is *"always"* better to write portable code, and clearly you don't either. :-)

Comment: Eh... that was a typo. I meant 8 bytes. I'll fix it right now.

Comment: @CodyGray Fixed now :p.